# DHT11 module compilation error

Tags: raspbian, kernel, cross-compilation, modules

I try to compile the source code of DHT11 module given in [[https://www.endian.se/content/?p=127]](https://www.endian.se/content/?p=127%5d) . I have followed the step of KERNEL compilation in [[http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2013/01/16/compiling-kernel-modules-for-raspberry-pi.aspx ] and succeed. whene I try to compile the file dht11km.c I get error :

```
make arch=ARM CROSS_COMPILE=/home/makhlouf/rpi/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi- -C /home/makhlouf/rpi/linux M=/home/makhlouf/temperature modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/makhlouf/rpi/linux'
/home/makhlouf/rpi/linux/arch/x86/Makefile:98: stack protector enabled but no compiler support
  CC [M]  /home/makhlouf/temperature/dht11km.o
arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'
arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-mmx'
arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-sse'
arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-red-zone'
arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mcmodel=kernel'
arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-maccumulate-outgoing-args'
make[2]: *** [/home/makhlouf/temperature/dht11km.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/makhlouf/temperature] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/makhlouf/rpi/linux'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Makefile :

```
obj-m += dht11km.o

all:
    make arch=ARM CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} -C /home/makhlouf/rpi/linux M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /home/makhlouf/rpi/linux M=$(PWD) clean
```

linux source is in `/home/makhlouf/rpi/linux`

Comment: Have you considered a userland solution?  There is a method using Python/SPI which seems 100% reliable.  I have my own Python DHT22 module which uses any spare gpio and has error rates of roughly one bad read per 40,000.  However I have seen the DHT22 become unresponsive with my method.  I have never seen unresponsiveness with the SPI method.

Comment: thanks @joan but it's home work, I should made it with c. and compile the module.

Comment: Homework was different in my day! I don't know anything about building kernel modules.  The line /home/makhlouf/rpi/linux/arch/x86/Makefile looks odd.  RPi (ARM) and x86 do not mix.

Comment: I think you're right, in the directory /home/makhlouf/rpi/linux/arch/ there is arm, x86 ...., I'm sure i had an options error when compiling the kernel, I will review it

Comment: this like works fine for me 

[ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167411/how-to-compile-a-kernel-module-for-raspberry-pi ]

Comment: this like works fine for me 
 [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167411/how-to-compile-a-kernel-module-for-raspberry-pi ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps required to build a kernel module on Raspbian.

1. Perform an `sudo rpi-update`

   See https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update for details on
   `rpi-update`.  You have to be on the latest firmware and associated kernel to be able to perform the next step.
2. Install and run `rpi-source` to install the source code that built the latest kernel that you are running.  This will create the correct entry in `/lib/modules` for the kernel that you are running.  Note: you don't need to be root to run this, however the script will perform certain tasks using `sudo` and the root password will be requested during the script execution.

   Instructions to install `rpi-source` can be found at https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki

Once those steps are performed you should be able to `make` your kernel module.

```
johnma@raspberrypi ~ $ cd dht11km/
johnma@raspberrypi ~/dht11km $ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.12.19+/build M=/home/johnma/dht11km modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/johnma/linux-c3db7205bcd8988cf7c185e50c8849542554b1f5'
  CC [M]  /home/johnma/dht11km/dht11km.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/johnma/dht11km/dht11km.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/johnma/dht11km/dht11km.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johnma/linux-c3db7205bcd8988cf7c185e50c8849542554b1f5'


johnma@raspberrypi ~/dht11km $ sudo insmod dht11km.ko gpio_pin=4 format=3
May 14 21:58:58 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2985.291192] dht11: driver registered!
johnma@raspberrypi ~/dht11km $ sudo mknod /dev/dht11 c 80 0
johnma@raspberrypi ~/dht11km $ cat /dev/dht11 
Temperature: 2C
Humidity: 0%
Result:OK
```

Comment: rpi-source command not found. sudo apt-get install rpi-source : Unable to locate package rpi-source

Comment: Added link for instructions on how to install `rpi-source`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to build (make) the module on my Raspberry Pi itself instead of cross compiling it on another machine.

However, I needed to perform the steps listed at the end to avoid the following error:

```
raspberrypi ~/dht11km $ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.25+/build M=/home/johnma/dht11km modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.10.25+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The following instructions from [this article](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=67347&p=495080) allowed the make to complete without error.

1. Try to install linux-headers

   `sudo apt-get install linux-headers`

   You get a message that you try to install a virtual package and you have to install a concrete package. You find a list of concrete packages.
2. Install the concrete package

   `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.10-3-rpi`
3. Now the trick. You have to link the new build folder with the missing folder.

   `sudo ln -s /lib/modules/3.10-3-rpi/build /lib/modules/3.10.25+/build`

Here's what `modinfo` shows after the make completes:

```
~/dht11km $ modinfo ./dht11km.ko
filename:       /home/johnma/dht11km/./dht11km.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Nigel Morton
description:    DHT11 temperature/humidity sendor driver for Raspberry Pi GPIO.
depends:
vermagic:       3.10-3-rpi mod_unload modversions ARMv6 p2v8
parm:           format:int
parm:           gpio_pin:Format of output (int)
parm:           driverno:Driver handler major value (int)
```

Comment: the module compile, but cant insert it with insmod, because it has been compiled with 3.10.3 and insered in 3.10.25 kernel version. so I should  use 3.10.3 kernel binary

Answer (score 2):

the answers of this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167411/how-to-compile-a-kernel-module-for-raspberry-pi] works fine. You first need kernel headers and the corresponding kernel binary to build the module.