# Raspbian kernel source compilation configuration

Tags: raspbian, kernel, cross-compilation

I try to compile Raspbian, [ http://hermess.no-ip.org/rpi/index.php ]
when I Prime kernel with the old config: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} oldconfig` I get a lot lot of dialog messages, so is the file `.config` useless??? [image]

Comment: may i ask, what's the purpose of your compiling Raspbian?

Comment: I want to compile a module, and in all links I found, they compile first the kernel.

Comment: i asked before this question : http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15902/dht11-module-compilation-error , and I think that problem is in kernel configuration, I see X86 in path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's the correct behavior of **`make oldconfig`** command.

It picks up the available `.config`, in this case belonging to an older kernel version, and produces a new `.config` file making the proper corrections where possible and asking to the user whenever new and empty entries are found.

As you can see in your screenshot, the `make oldconfig` command is giving itself the proper `[Y/n/m]` answers until it's able to do so. When it encounters the `CONFIG_ARPD` line and it needs to *embed/disable* it (the *module* option is not given for this entry), the script finds that the entry is present in the kernel you want to compile but not in the `.config` you supplied. Given that the script has no clue of what to do, it asks to the user.

Now the problem is: what answers should I give to the `make oldconfig` command? Unfortunately there is no simple, algorithmic answer to this question and this is why the Linux kernel compilation is still artisanry. As a general rule of thumb, apart of googling for the simbol name (e.g. what is CONFIG_ARPD?), whenever you encounter a new driver that you never heard of, it's safe to say `[m]` because modules almost always just increase your kernel size, giving (almost always) no other performance hit until they're actually loaded and used. Conversely, if you say `CONFIG_NETFILTER=y` or even worst `CONFIG_SMP=y` you must know that just for enabling one of this (huge) key-features, your Linux kernel will be slower compared to a *UP* (UniProcessor == non-SMP) kernel with Netfilter disabled, because this kernel entries translate one-to-one to large #ifdef blocks that are enabled, compiled and executed.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just press enter for all message and it create a binary file image of 6MB and zimage of 3MB. is it normal size?????.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a perfectly reasonable size. Pressing just enter you accepted all the defaults proposed by the kernel's scripts. Actually that's the fastest way to obtain a working kernel image. If you don't have any particular need in terms of memory/cpu usage, you probably adopted the best method of configuring a Linux kernel :)

Comment: now that I compiled Raspbian source, what shall I do to  load it to empty SD card?? can I just copy it to SD card????

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you don't want to create your own .config file you can take it from the RPi with shown below process

On the RPi

`zcat /proc/config.gz > .config`

and then copy the `.config` file to your build directory (which you want to cross-compile) or default configuration file is found in your downloaded kernel source at `arch/arm/configs/bcmrpi_defconfig` you just copy it to build directory to `.config` file.

Then you can build the kernel

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}
```

it's shown at http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation page, below the **Perform the compilation** chapter. And there is more things in this page about the cross-compiling of the RPi kernel.